# UIViewController in storyboard with nib file

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard, nib, expandable

Hi can I ask if can I mix the xib with my `UIViewController` in storyboard? Like they share a controller in their files owner because I'm planning to create a expandable view by using nib as the expandedview and I want to pass a value from nib file to the `UIViewController` in storyboard. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't recommend you mix xib and view controller from storyboard and hook them all together.
If you want to add a UIView as an extended view to your view controller you can do something like this:

```
// Load the first view inside our xib from main bundle
UIView *view = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"nib_name" owner:self options:nil][0];

// Define new X,Y to our view
float new_x_position = 0;
float new_y_position = 400;
view.frame = CGRectMake(new_x_position, new_y_position, CGRectGetWidth(view.frame), CGRectGetHeight(view.frame));

// UILabel inside our nib, '111' is the tag we set to our UILabel
UILabel *label = (UILabel*)[view viewWithTag:111];

// Add our view to the current view as a sub view
[self.view addSubview:view];
```

I hope I understood you correctly.

Comment: Thanks Idan I get your point but how can I touch the elements of my nib? Like for example I want to change the UILabel of my nib

Answer (score 0):

In storyboard you are not provided with xibs, but if you want to use them to load from nib then use :

```
MyViewController *viewController = [[MyViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"CustomDownloadedXib" bundle:nil];
```

Comment: Better use "awakeAfterUsingCoder"